# How to use WaitForCursor?

Tags: vbscript, secure-crt

I'm using WaitForString command to pause my script until the desired text appears on screen. However I notice that the screen stops "printing" as soon as that happens.  I'd rather wait until the whole screen finishes refreshing.

I suspect that instead of WaitForString("text"), I could use WaitForCursor; when the screen is complete, I can use Get("text").

However, I cannot find any documentation that explains the WaitForCursor command. How would I use it in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Have a read through of this manual for secure-crt and scripting with vbscript

[Scripting Essentials (PDF)](https://www.vandyke.com/support/tips/scripting/scripting_essentials.pdf)

I expect you would use the command itself as `crt.Screen.WaitForCursor(timeout)` although I've never used this software myself so that's just a guess